# Cannot reason with Cormen (4th ed) problem on Merge-Sort

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

Confused with Cormen's (4th ed.) 2.3-2 problem. It states the following:

> The test in line 1 of the Merge-Sort procedure reads "if p >= r" rather than "if p != r". If Merge-Sort is called with p > r, then the subarray A[p : r] is empty. Argue that as long as the initial call of Merge-Sort(A, 1, n) has n >= 1, the test "if p != r" suffices to ensure that no recursive call has p > r.

Merge-Sort pseudo code:

```
Merge-Sort(A, p, r)
1    if p >= r
2        return
3    q = math.floor((p + r) / 2)
4    Merge-Sort(A, p, q)
5    Merge-Sort(A, q + 1, r)
6    // Merge A[p : q] and A[q + 1 : r] into A[p : r]
7    Merge(A, p, q, r)
```

But if we change first line condition to `if p != r` we'll get the following.
In case `n = 1`, we call `Merge-Sort(A, 1, 1)`. Line 1 — `p != r` — evaluates to false. We skip line 2, `q = math.floor((1 + 1) / 2) = 1 ---> q = 1`. On line 4 we call `Merge-Sort(A, 1, 1)` and after this call returns we go to line 5 and call `Merge-Sort(A, 2, 1)` which is clearly a recursive call that has `p > r`.

What is wrong with my reasoning and how can I solve the problem?

UPD 1: @500 - Internal Server Error, thanks for replying. I should have stated that earlier — the convention of the pseudo code is that first index is 1 and last equals to array length. So in case of array of length 1 I should call `Merge-Sort(A, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, you cannot just replace `if p >= r` with `if p != r`. `p != r` is the condition which should lead you to executing lines 3 through 7, so if you want to keep the same program structure, you'd need `if p == r / return`.

This problem with the book has already been reported and the publishers say it will be corrected in the next printing. See the [official errata](https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/11599/e4-bugs.html) for the 4th edition.